# How can I view a Skype conversation that is older than 3 months?

Tags: windows-7, skype

I need to view an old Skype conversation.

This conversation is older than 3 months, Skype only allows me to select

```
"Show messages from: Yesterday - 7 days - 30 days - 3 months"
```

I need to see messages older than this.

I have searched, and everyone says, "it's possible", but doesn't say how. I know that the history is stored in the main.db file, but that doesn't help, it appears to be in `sqllite` format.

So, how can I view old messages in Skype.

Note: I did migrate from MSN Messenger, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I suggest you go and ask skype (Microsoft) directly why the heck they cannot allow skype to have unlimited chat history. It is ridiculous. Anyway, I am pretty sure at least NSA has your history older then 3 months ... :D

Comment: I asked on the Skype forums (man I hate forums), if I get a proper response then I'll post it here as an answer. @Vitas, per the NSA comment, have you seen this? www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qrlDGhoI1Q‎ ;-)

Comment: There are two possible reasons for why I cannot view older than 3 months. a) `Corrupted .db file` b) `new .db file` (my issue, I'm dumb), we changed from local login to domain login in Nov, which is why I only have 3 months of data because I'm now a "new user".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a unlimeted chat history but its stored localy on you pc and you need to set up you skype to save all messages.
So I think you can´t if you dont have set up you skype for that. My skype shows me also the options 6 month, 1 year and all.

You can change log settings in skype options at the advanced chat-options.

Comment: Wow really! This must have been a recent Skype update because it really was not possible to set anything bigger then 3 months last time I checked!

Comment: I dont think its a recent update because i never chaned it or i dont recall it. Just took a look at my skype because i knew i used to look up stuff that happend 6 month ago.

Answer (score 0):

Open Skype > Conversation > View Older message > select time

You can change log settings in skype options at the advanced chat-options.

Answer (score 0):

To change the log settings in Skype 7.41:

[image]